# Remove Invalid characters in an e-mail address

Tags: java, regex, string, email

I'm trying to find out how to remove all invalid characters in an email address.

Ex: email="taeo͝';st@yy.com"(. is an email character) and the result should be: email = "taest@yy.com"

I'm using the following email pattern:

```
String email_pattern = "^[^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"+ "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$]";

String modifiedEmail = email.replaceAll(email_pattern,"");
```

But the above code is giving the result: email = "aest@yy.com" but expected "taest@yy.com"

Any suggestions or a better approach would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with a [unicode email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844431/are-email-addresses-allowed-to-contain-non-alphanumeric-characters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it resolved by using pattern matcher.

```
email = "testo͝';@.com.my"   
String EMAIl_PATTERN = "[^a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&@'*+-/=?^_`{|}~.]+";
modifiedEmail = email.replaceAll(EMAIl_PATTERN, "");
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a nice blog post of why you shouldn't filter your email adresses:
http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

TL;DR: Check if there is an @ (optionally a period) and send a test mail.
David suggests to use this regular expression:

```
/.+@.+\..+/
```

Comment: Great article. I love this solution. I also like how I can actually memorize this regular expression for future use.

Comment: My use case is different, I create my own e-mail addresses from names, names that might contain spaces, 8-bit characters etc. Any good way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Further thinking:
You could also be testing for know providers of email adresses used without authentication (e.g. http://trashmail.com/).