# In MySQL How do I specify Collation for WHERE-IN clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, collation, mysql-5.5

In MySQL, I can specify the collation if I have a standard WHERE clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE email_address = 'foo@bar.com' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

However the following fails if I have multiple email addresses in a WHERE-IN clause

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE email_address IN ('foo@bar.com', 'test@test.com') COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

What am I missing to get this to work?  Mysql 5.5.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use collation for `email` column which by definition should always have only ascii-safe characters? And what collation is the column itself?

Comment: I wish that were the case. Emails can have all sorts of interesting characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844431/are-email-addresses-allowed-to-contain-non-alphanumeric-characters

Comment: oh that's interesting. Why didn't you create the column with utf8 collation then?

Comment: It should be, and I plan on changing it.  The collate is a temporary stopgap solution.

Comment: "nothing is so permanent as a temporary" ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you specify it after every string:

```
WHERE email_address IN ('foo@bar.com' COLLATE utf8_general_ci, 'test@test.com' COLLATE utf8_general_ci)
```

?

Comment: It appears this works when having only  a single COLLATE clause within IN.

Comment: @Newtang: how exactly? And what happens if you specify it several times?

Comment: I tried putting it after the first entry, and at the very end.  I didn't test it extremely thoroughly, but it seems like the results are the same as putting it in several times.  I did notice a significant slowdown for large queries on occasion though.

Comment: @Newtang: it's an expected slowdown - fullscan isn't a cheap operation

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( email_address, 'foo@bar.com,test@test.com' COLLATE utf8_general_ci );
```

Comment: Any reason to prefer `FIND_IN_SET` (which cannot be optimized well) over `IN` in this case?

Comment: @zerkms no prefer but an alternative to your answer